# _pickedTime.format(context) not working in real device flutter(TimeOfDay to String)

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, datetime-format, timeofday

I always get this error
[Trying to read   from 08:43 at position 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XtZl.jpg) whenever am converting from TimeOfDay to String using `_pickedTime.format(context)`. It throws the error on my real device but works perfectly on my emulator. How do I solve this error. Below is more codes fo review:

```
DateTime date = DateFormat.jm().parse(task.startTime.toString());
        var myTime = DateFormat("HH:mm").format(date);
        notificationService.scheduleNotification(
          hour: int.parse(myTime.toString().split(":")[0]),
          minutes: int.parse(myTime.toString().split(":")[1]),
          task: task
```

Then on my time conversion this:

```
String _endTime = '9:30PM';
  String _startTime = DateFormat('hh:mm a').format(DateTime.now()).toString();

  _getTimeFromUser({required bool isStartTime}) async {
    var pickedTime = await _showTimePicker();
    String formattedTime = pickedTime.format(context);
    if(isStartTime == true) {
      setState(() {
        _startTime = formattedTime;
      });
    }else if(isStartTime == false) {
      setState(() {
        _endTime = formattedTime;
      });
    }else if(pickedTime == null) {
      debugPrint('Time Cancelled');}
  }

  _showTimePicker() {
    return showTimePicker(context: context,
        initialEntryMode: TimePickerEntryMode.input,
        initialTime: TimeOfDay(
            hour: int.parse(_startTime.split(':')[0]),
            minute: int.parse(_startTime.split(':')[1].split(' ')[0])));
  }
```

Comment: Hi, Did you solve this issue?
I am experiencing the same problem using flutter for web. I mean, this works like charm on debug mode, but It does not work running on the website (release mode, after it was compiled using `flutter build web`).
Note: I was using flutter SDK 3.3.7 and I have updated to 3.3.10. I did not upgraded to the last flutter version yet, because I am migrating all the app to the null safety approach.