# Flutter error: converting TimeOfDay to String via pickedTime.format() using TextFormField widget

Tags: android, flutter, google-chrome

Whenever I am trying to convert from **TimeOfDay** to String using **pickedTime.format(context)** on the context of **TextFormField** and **Form** widgets. It throws an error on released versions (built by `flutter build apk` or `flutter build web`) of the [android real phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73727599/pickedtime-formatcontext-not-working-in-real-device-fluttertimeofday-to-stri/76596409#76596409) and chrome, but It works fine on Android emulator, Firefox, or Edge.

The error is: *Trying to read from 14:35 at position 6*.

Just to let you know, yesterday (July, 1st, 2023) I tested with:

- Window 10
- Android 10
- flutter 3.3.10 and all version of the packages related to this
  flutter SDK, for example Intl 0.17.0, etc.
- Firefox 114.0.2 (64-bit) => All good.
- Edge 114.0.1823.67 (Official build) (64-bit) => All good.
- Chrome 114.0.5735.199 (Official Build) (64-bit) => Error.

Release version tested with Firefox
[image]

Release version tested with Edge
[image]

Release version tested with Chrome
[image]

Let us hope a future update of Google Chrome and Android will solve this issue.

Here is a minimal example to check it out:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  String? resTime;
  /// get picked time
  /// input params: context and an String DateTime
  /// output: String time picked or current time
  Future<String> pickTime(
      BuildContext context, String paramStringDateTime) async {
    print("Inside pickTime method, paramStringDateTime: $paramStringDateTime");
    String returnTime = DateFormat(
        'HH:mm:ss')
        .format(DateTime.tryParse(paramStringDateTime) ?? DateTime.now());
    print(
        "Inside pickTime method, getting returnTime before showTimePicker: $returnTime");
    TimeOfDay? pickedTime = await showTimePicker(
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(DateTime.parse(paramStringDateTime)),
      context: context,
//       // These following lines are not mandatory
//       builder: (context, childWidget) {
//         return MediaQuery(
//           // Using 24-Hour format // If you want 12-Hour format, just change alwaysUse24HourFormat to false or remove all the builder argument
//             data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: true),
//             child: childWidget!);
//       },
    );
    print("Inside pickTime method, pickedTime: $pickedTime");
    if (pickedTime != null) {
      // if (!mounted) return returnTime;
      returnTime = DateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
          .format(DateFormat("hh:mm a").parse(pickedTime.format(context)));
      print("Inside pickTime method, returnTime: $returnTime");
    }

    return returnTime;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () async {
                resTime = await pickTime(context, (resTime != null ? '2023-01-01 $resTime' : '2023-01-01 14:31:00.000'));
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: Text(resTime ?? "22:30"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Just an update (July 17th, 2023)**

I have converted all app for flutter 3.10.6 and the same issue is there, I mean it works on Firefox, Edge, or Android simulator. On the other hand, it is not working on Chrome (Version 114.0.5735.199 Official Build - 64-bit) and Android real device.
Here is my flutter doctor output command:
[image]

The issue is happening on Google Chrome:
[image]

Comment: Due to `returnTime` is a String variable, I could solve this issue by changing the line:
`returnTime = DateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(DateFormat("hh:mm a").parse(pickedTime.format(context)));`
to:
`returnTime ='${pickedTime.hour.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${pickedTime.minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';`